# Weird result when access the stored elements in an array

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, igraph

I initialized the array `rhs` to store the data resulted from the function `rbf` as below:

```
float rhs[m][n1+n2];
        for (i=0; i<m; i++){
         igraph_edge(&graph, i, &from, &to);
         igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v1, from, IGRAPH_ALL);
         igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v2, to, IGRAPH_ALL);
         n2 = igraph_vector_size(&v2);
         n1 = igraph_vector_size(&v1);
         for (j=0; j < n2 ; j++) {
              rhs[i][j] = rbf(to, (int) VECTOR(v2)[j]);
              printf("%d %d %f\n", to, (int) VECTOR(v2)[j], rhs[i][j]);
          }
         for (j=0; j < n1; j++) {
              rhs[i][j+n2] = rbf(from, (int) VECTOR(v1)[j]);
              printf("%d %d %d %d %f\n", from, (int) VECTOR(v1)[j], j, j+n2, rhs[i][j+n2]);
          }
printf("\n");
     }
```

The output:

```
2 1 0.367879
2 3 0.367879
2 4 0.018316
1 2 0 3 0.367879

3 2 0.367879
3 4 0.367879
2 1 0 2 0.367879
2 3 1 3 0.367879
2 4 2 4 0.018316 

4 2 0.018316
4 3 0.367879
4 5 0.367879
2 1 0 3 0.367879
2 3 1 4 0.367879 <-- ** here rhs[i = 2][( j+(n2=3) ) =  4] = 0.367879 **
2 4 2 5 0.018316 <-- ** here rhs[i = 2][( j+(n2=3) ) =  5] = 0.018316 **

4 2 0.018316
4 3 0.367879
4 5 0.367879
3 2 0 3 0.367879
3 4 1 4 0.367879

5 4 0.367879
4 2 0 1 0.018316
4 3 1 2 0.367879
4 5 2 3 0.367879
```

When I try to access this array as seen below, the order of only two elements inside it is not the same as when they were stored! I don't know why it is replacing them with each other!

```
for (i=0; i<m; i++){
         igraph_edge(&graph, i, &from, &to);
         igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v1, from, IGRAPH_ALL);
         igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v2, to, IGRAPH_ALL);
         n2 = igraph_vector_size(&v2);
         n1 = igraph_vector_size(&v1);
 for (j=0; j < (n1+n2) ; j++) {
    printf("%li %li %f", i, j, rhs[i][j]);
printf("\n");
  }  
printf("\n");    
}
printf("\n%f", rhs[2][5]);
```

And the outputs:

```
    0 0 0.367879
    0 1 0.367879
    0 2 0.018316
    0 3 0.367879

    1 0 0.367879
    1 1 0.367879
    1 2 0.367879
    1 3 0.367879
    1 4 0.018316

    2 0 0.018316
    2 1 0.367879
    2 2 0.367879
    2 3 0.367879
    2 4 0.018316 <-- ** here is a strange element rhs[2][4] should equal 0.367879 **
    2 5 0.367879 <-- ** here is a strange element rhs[2][5] should equal 018316 **

    3 0 0.018316
    3 1 0.367879
    3 2 0.367879
    3 3 0.367879
    3 4 0.367879

    4 0 0.367879
    4 1 0.018316
    4 2 0.367879
    4 3 0.367879


    0.367879 <-- it is this one! should equal 0.018316 but it is replacing rhs[2][5] with rhs[2][4]
```

I would like to know why the order of elements when accessing them in the array is not the same as it is when storing these element? It is a result of what exactly?

**Addition:**

The file `toy` consists of the toy data which is in the form

```
1 2
2 3
2 4
3 4
4 5
```

Here is all of the code if you would like to compile it:

```
#include <igraph/igraph.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define sigma 1
    /* Declare and define the rbf function */

float rbf(int a, int b);
float rbf(int a, int b) {
               double inverse;
               double exp(double x;);
               double x;
               double result;

               inverse = ( 1/(sigma*sigma) );
               x = (- inverse * ( (a - b)*(a - b) ) );
               result = exp(x);
               return (result); 
 }

/* Define a function to print a vector in a file using the functions defined in igraph package */

void print_vector(igraph_vector_t *v, FILE *file) {
     long int i;
     for (i=0; i < igraph_vector_size(v); i++) {
        fprintf(file, "%li \n", (long int) VECTOR(*v)[i]);
      }
     fprintf(file,"\n");
  }

int main(void)
{
     igraph_t graph; 
     igraph_bool_t false;
     int ret, n1, n2;
     igraph_vector_t v1, v2;
     long int i, j, k, n, m ;
     igraph_integer_t from, to;
     igraph_adjlist_t adjlist;
     FILE *file;

     /* read the graph from a file using igraph package */
     file = fopen("toy", "r");
          if(!file){
                     return 1;
           }
     igraph_read_graph_edgelist(&graph, file, 
                   0, false);
           fclose(file);
            //return 2;

  /* initialize two vectors to store v1, v2 to store vertices */
     igraph_vector_init(&v1, (igraph_vcount(&graph)) );
     igraph_vector_init(&v2, (igraph_vcount(&graph)) );

    n = igraph_vcount(&graph); /* number of vertices in the graph */
    m = igraph_ecount(&graph); /* number of edges in the graph */


float rhs[m][n1+n2];
    for (i=0; i<m; i++){
                 igraph_edge(&graph, i, &from, &to);
                 igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v1, from, IGRAPH_ALL);
                 igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v2, to, IGRAPH_ALL);
                 n2 = igraph_vector_size(&v2);
                 n1 = igraph_vector_size(&v1);


                 for (j=0; j < n2 ; j++) {
                     rhs[i][j] = rbf(to, (int) VECTOR(v2)[j]);
                     printf("%d %d %f\n", to, (int) VECTOR(v2)[j], rhs[i][j]);
                 }
                 for (j=0; j < n1; j++) {
                     rhs[i][j+n2] = rbf(from, (int) VECTOR(v1)[j]);
                     printf("%d %d %li %li %f\n", from, (int) VECTOR(v1)[j], j, j+n2, rhs[i][j+n2]);
                 }
printf("\n");
         }

  for (i=0; i<m; i++){
                 igraph_edge(&graph, i, &from, &to);
                 igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v1, from, IGRAPH_ALL);
                 igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v2, to, IGRAPH_ALL);
                 n2 = igraph_vector_size(&v2);
                 n1 = igraph_vector_size(&v1);
                 for (j=0; j < (n1+n2) ; j++) {
                        printf("%f", rhs[i][j]);
                  }  
                 printf("\n");

     }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.  You should follow a coding style guide (or your own, but do it).  Here's a good one: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html

Comment: `n1` and `n2` are uninitialized when you do `float rhs[m][n1+n2];`. All of this is undefined behavior. You didn't include the `toy` file needed to reproduce the problem. Please fix you indentation. Please, if you compile with gcc, compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` and fix all errors.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` (or whatever warning options your compiler has) to see this kind of errors

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks..n1 and n2 are defined at the beginning, see under int main(void)
{.. } unless I need to define them again inside the function
Also all data in file toy are included in the question! there are no other data..
For the indentation, I've never worked on C and I am doing my best to do these things.btw I followed a tutorial for indentation!

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Thanks for the recommendation. I used it but nothing is related to the problem! it is only notifying me about integers I defined them but I didn't use them

Comment: `I used it but nothing is related to the problem!` - well I clearly got `warning: ‘n1’ may be used uninitialized in this function` and same for `n2`

Comment: @KamilCuk I got the same warning for n not n1 or n2 !

Comment: When many errors are present, the compiler doesn't always find them all.  You have to solve them one by one.

Comment: Defining a variable is not the same as assigning a value to it.  You need to give it a value before using it, which is exactly what the compiler is telling you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n1` and `n2` are uninitialized before the line `rhs[m][n1+n2]`. All the behavior of your program may/is undefined behavior.

```
int ret, n1, n2;
... code that does not touches n1 nor n2 ...
float rhs[m][n1+n2];
```

The variables `n1` and `n2` are not initialized before use. They are used to declare a variable length array VLA. The compiler allocates memory for VLA at line `float rhs[m][n1 + n2]`. Because the variables are not initialized, the values of the variables have what's called "indeterminate" value (read as: any value). The compiler allocates an unknown (for the programmer) number of floats for the `rhs` array. The `n1` and `n2` may be negative, in which case undefined behavior happens. You should use to dynamic allocation instead.

Also using VLA for big arrays (or using them at all) is not recommended. You can't detect failure. You don't know if it will fail and when. They are not that much portable and made optional in C. Don't use VLA, use dynamic allocation when possible.

```
float **rhs = malloc(sizeof(rhs[0]) * m);
if (rhs == NULL) { /* handle error; */ }
for (i = ...) {
    .. later...
    rhs[i] = malloc(sizeof(rhs[i][0]) * (n1 + n2));
    if (rhs[i] == NULL) { /* handle error */ }
}
.. later ..
for (i = ... ){ 
    free(rhs[i]);
}
free(rhs);
```

Notes:

- use `size_t` type to represent sizes of objects and counts of elements in an array. `for (size_t i = 0; i < ... ; i++)` is a popular idiom.
- [Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html) is a good style guide in C files.
- From the linux kernel coding style: "number of local variables [...] shouldn’t exceed 5-10, or you’re doing something wrong".
- Always try to compile with all (sanity) warnings enabled. Try to fix all warnings.
- `igraph_bool_t false;` "false" is a macro defined in `stdbool.h`. I suggest to rename the variable name, in case you want later to include `stdbool.h`.

Comment: Or big enough static arrays